# write data at desired line in already existing file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a text file which already has 40 lines of data . I want to write data just before last two lines in a file. I am newbie to c++. I searched online and found few functions like fseek and seekp, but I am not getting how those those functions to change the lines. Can you please give some pointers for this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your file using a `std::ifstream`
2. Read the whole file into a `std::vector<std::string>` with an entry for each line in the file (you can use `std::getline()` and `std::vector<std::string>::push_back()` methods to realize this).
3. Close the `std::ifstream`
4. Change the vector entry at the line index you want to change, or alternatively insert additional entries to the vector using `std::vector<std::string>::insert()`
5. Open your file using a `std::ofstream`
6. Write the vectors content back to the file (just iterate over the vector and output each entry to the file).

You shouldn't mess around with `seek` functions in this case; particularly not, if the replacements size changes dynamically.

Comment: can I use this for tchar routine?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _'tchar routine'_? Which particular one? Usually MSVC++ should get it right upon the global definition of `TCHAR`, if you're bothering about that. Think they'll auto translate to `std::wstring` if necessary or s.th. like that.

Comment: I wouldn't read in the whole file. Read one line at a time, write one line at a time. When you reach the right place in the file insert your new lines. This method saves memory. Doesn't matter for 40 lines but when the text files reach a gigabyte in size you don't want bad habits.

Comment: @ZanLynx In general, yes! But he was talking about a use case having a 40 line file, so I didn't bother about this. Also I didn't want to give him a code sample (not even in pseudo code), for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You say C++, so I assume you mean that and not C. A FIFO comes to mind for this purpose.

```
$ cat last_two_lines.c | ./a.out

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>

main ()
{
  std::deque<std::string> fifo;
  while (!std::cin.eof()) {
    std::string buffer;
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    fifo.push_back(buffer);
    if (fifo.size() > 2) {
      std::cout << fifo.front() << "\n";
      fifo.pop_front();
    }
  }
  std::cout << "    // LINE INSERTED" << "\n";
  while (fifo.size() > 0) {
    std::cout << fifo.front() << "\n";
    fifo.pop_front();
  }
  return 0;
    // LINE INSERTED
}
```